# Struggling with BoxLayout in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

Whats up guys I'm struggling to understand how to implement BoxLayout or any layout in java swing. I have been looking at tutorials on oracle and others but i just can't get it to work. This is for an assignment in college so I would appreciate not giving me the solution straight up but maybe just point me in the right direction. I think the problem is my code is different to what is in the tutorials so I'm not sure what goes where.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;


class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField input = new JTextField(10);
    JButton but1 = new JButton ("Convert");
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JTextArea output = new JTextArea(1, 20);



    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Window gui = new Window();
            String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

        }


    public Window()
        {
            super("Swing Window");
            setSize(500, 200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            panel.add(input);
            but1.addActionListener(this);
            add(panel);
            panel.add(output);
            label.setText ("please enter celsius to be converted to Fahrenheit");
            panel.add(but1);
            panel.add(label);
            setVisible(true);   
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String inputStr = input.getText();
        inputStr = inputStr.trim();
        double input = Double.parseDouble(inputStr);
        double fahrenheit = input * 1.8 + 32;


        if (event.getSource() == but1)
        {
            output.setText("Here is degrees celsius " + input + " converted `to Fahrenheit: " + fahrenheit);`
        }
    }


}
```

There is the executable code.

Comment: Please post your code here in your question. Don't use external websites to post your code. Thanks. `just point me in the right direction` the right direction to where? You never said what your problem is

Comment: 1) code should be posted in the forum with your question 2) We have no idea what your problem is. What is the requirement? What is currently happening. `I think the problem is my code is different to what is in the tutorials ` - if that is the problem then download the demo code from the tutorial again so that it is exactly the same. Then you change one line at a time, and test and repeat until you get what your want. Then any time it stops working you know what line you changed.

Comment: 1)Sorry I have posted code from pasetbin before I didnt know it was not allowed. 2) "I think the problem is my code is different to what is in the tutorials so I'm not sure what goes where"  That is taken from my question I have been using oracle but don't understand how to implement what is in the tutorial in my code.

Comment: *I'm not sure what goes where*. What are you trying to achieve? *but don't understand how to implement what is in the tutorial in my code.* and what's that thing that you don't understand or what do you want to implement? Also, your code doesn't compile.

Comment: At the moment my layout is from left to right. I would like to have it go from top to bottom. Also I just want to be able to understand how to use Layout managers. When I said point in the right direction I meant maybe anyone knows of other tutorials that I haven't been able to find myself. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: So, you're asking us for tutorials? If so, this question is off-topic for StackOverlfow. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and lastly learn [How to do a runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BigBoss04772 You can edit your question to improve it. You can put the code into your question, and add what you just noted in your comment regarding what you see compared to what you expect.

Comment: `At the moment my layout is from left to right. I would like to have it go from top to bottom` - so did you read the tutorial??? How is your code different from the tutorial. It is up to you to do basic debugging. That is why I suggested you `start with working code`. BoxLayout supports both horizontal and vertical alignment but it can't read your mind so it is up to you to specify what you want. Since you refuse to post code in the forum you are on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skimmed your code, but did not execute it.  As others already mentioned in the comments, it is helpful for you to describe what the program does and to describe what you expect/want it to do.  Otherwise we are just guessing as to what is wrong and what would be correct.

From my reading of your code, I think you see nothing displayed. *Correction: you did call `add()`; as indicated in one of your more recent comments*  Here are some notes/explanations:

- Your method `addComponentsToPane()` is never called, thus you never create any `BoxLayout` objects
- Recommendation: variable names begin with lowercase, and don't name a variable the same as a class; it easily creates confusion when reading the code.  Thus don't name the argument `Window`.
- Your method `addComponentsToPane()`, if it were called, creates a Layout object and sets it on the component passed to it but does not actually add any components.  The name is thus misleading.
- A JFrame's content pane has a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) by default. When components are added without any additional constraints, the BorderLayout chooses to place the components in a certain order (starting with [`BorderLayout.CENTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER)).  See [documentation of the JFrame class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) where it says the default is BorderLayout.
- A [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html#JPanel--), when created with the default constructor has a [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) by default.
- Since your program never changed the panel's layout manager, this is what gives you the left-to-right flow that you observed.
- You want to set the panel's layout to a vertical BoxLayout before you add components to it

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to give me advice and try to help me instead of just pointing out everything that is wrong with my post. Thanks a million pal.